# Extract the features from Doc2Vec in Python

Tags: python, doc2vec

For a small project I need to extract the features obtained from Doc2Vec object in gensim.

I have used `vector = model.infer_vector(words)` is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if `words` is a list of word strings, preprocessed/tokenized the same way as training data was fed to the `model` during training.